# hmvc templates not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc

hi i am currently learning to use hmvc and i am watching this video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DS0GeknUkds

this video is about templates and my templates are not working. i have copied all the code that he does but i am using xampp.

here is my link. `http://localhost/ci_hmvc/index.php/Template/sample_templates`

i always get 404 Page Not Found

can someone tell me if my link is wrong or i havent done something that this guy did. thanks.

Comment: If your using CI 3 make sure your controller files have first letter upper case for class name and file name. `application > modules > home > controllers > Welcome.php` and `class Welcome extends MX_Controller {}`

Comment: And make sure your CI version is 3 and above because this https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/downloads only works on CI3

Comment: You also don't need to use upper case in url `http://localhost/ci_hmvc/index.php/template/sample_templates`

Comment: Do you have a webserver running on your PC? Because `localhost` indentifies your PC.

Comment: i am only running xampp. the first tutorial video before that is perfectly running into my pc

Comment: `  $this->load->view('templates/sample_template_v');` does this work? because i have my project in the modules and it says load view templates folder with filename sample_template_v

Comment: Have you loaded the module first ...?

Comment: what module? i only copied the one thats on the video that i linked above.